# Why doesn't Google map show specific point on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am using this code. My problem is that it is not showing the point which is displayed in maps.google.com. I am using Google API for 2.1. I am following this [Google map link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)
Check out the difference. You will notice in top left corner of garden.

[image]

Here my code is

```
package com.my.test;


public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {

MapView mapView; 
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {"-6.23", "106.83"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 
    mapView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to create overlay class for pointing something on the map.

Comment: This mean I have to create my specific point with image? That's make a scene.

Comment: ok. If you will answer on this question instead of comment. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the example [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android).

Its a very good link.

Comment: Yes I am following the same link. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Very good article pointed by you. I wish I could vote you twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to zoom a bit more. After that you will see all the points.

Comment: I have tried the zoom but result is same. The location is not displaying. I think I have to point it out form my code.